# Deploying a Hyperledger Composer blockchain business network to Hyperledger Fabric for a single organization

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

When I deployed a single-organization network in accordance with hyperledger composer, I used “composer network ping -c admin@tutorial-network” to test the business network connection and get this error.

Please help me, thank you

[image: When I deployed a single-organization network in accordance with hyperledger composer, I used “composer network ping -c admin@tutorial-network” to test the business network connection and get this error. Please help me, thank you]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this error...

"Error: Composer runtime (0.19.12) is not compatible with client (0.20.0)"

This looks like you have recently installed a new version of composer-cli (v0.20.0), and you are connecting to a Business Network that was originally installed with a composer client (v0.19.12).  You will need to force an upgrade of your Business Network to get the upgraded runtime used.

You need to do the following:

1. update the version of your business network in your `package.json` file.
2. Create a new .bna file with `composer archive create`
3. Then use `composer network install` to install the new version on the peer(s)
4. Use `composer network upgrade` to upgrade the running version of the Business Network.
5. Try the ping again :-)

Note that you need to use your PeerAdmin card for the network install and network start commands.

There is an example of this procedure in the [Composer Queries tutorial.](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/queries)

Comment: thank you!I tried to clean up the docker runtime and restart the fabric network，then the problem is solved, and your answer has given me some help.

Comment: docker kill $(docker ps -q)
    docker rm $(docker ps -aq)
    docker rmi $(docker images dev-* -q)